# how to add a delay in downstream project before it gets triggered by upstream project in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two Jobs configured on Jenkins job-A is upstream and job-B is downstream. once job-A completes the execution it triggers job-B but i want job-B should get start at least 5/10 minutes after job-A Completes. And in this case job-A starts at any random time in a day

Answer (score 2):

Use Jenkins Quiet Period feature to add some wait time before starting build.

Quiet-Period: Number of seconds to wait between consecutive runs of this job.

This can be configured at Jenkins global level or each individual Job level.
In your case configure Job-B with Quiet Period 5 or 10 minutes.

[image]